# Xcode signal to end app

Tags: c, xcode, macos, handler, signals

Does anyone knows what signal Xcode sends to kill a running program? I need an handler to do some cleanup before the programs gets killed. I already tried SIGINT and SIGTERM but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sends sinal SIGKILL. To verify you can open any application in debug mode and check the console when you stop the task.

However if it is kill -9 you cannot trap the signal.

What kind of clean up you want to do? I don't think there is any need to handle that event as you are doing it on purpose from XCode. If you are trying to send this signal to a process from outside Xcode like Terminal then in makes sense.

Comment: I use `sem_open` to initialize a posix semaphore. I need to call `sem_unlink` to release the string identifier of the semaphore (the application runs in a indefinite loop and it's not supposed to stop, so I cannot do it from the main). I tried also SIGKILL but it does not seems to work.

Comment: @Saphrosit: I dont think you are can handle the scenario by of trapping the signal and writing a handler for it. Can you use boost library in your code? I believe you can use scooped pointer or something like that? (I am not sure if there is something like scooped semaphore, but you can go in that direction for sure)

Comment: Since the semaphore identifier is saved in the kernel, I solved calling another program to simply call `sem_unlink`. Just a workaround but it works. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Is that programming continuously running or you invoke it? If it runs always make sure no body kills it. or if killed it gets relaunched.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't do that.

Use the appropriate delegate methods of your `AppDelegate`.

Comment: The app delegate methods are not called when the debugger teminates your process.

Comment: @Mike Weller True, but you shouldn't rely on that anyway - as your app might get killed on the real device as well without those triggers. IMO, it's a mistake to build code to handle this scenario into the app (more a design mistake).